# Cannot load string from Fragment's shared preferences

Tags: android

I am trying to save and load a string value from a fragment's shared preferences. However, the string I am committing to the preferences does not load back from the preferences. Here is my code.

```
// Prefs string handle
String NAME = "myPref";

// Get default prefs for the fragment
SharedPreferences defaultPrefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

// Commit a string to prefs
defaultPrefs.edit().putString(NAME, "Hello world!");
defaultPrefs.edit().commit();

// Load the string just commited to prefs
String commitedString = defaultPrefs.getString(NAME,"defaultString");

// Print the loaded string
// logs defaultString
// does not log Hello world!
Log.v(TAG,"commitedString value is "+commitedString);
```

Comment: Well of course not. The key is not the same

Comment: @Chisko Sorry, typo, still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are editing, putting a String, not committing, then editing again, putting nothing, and then committing.

Change

```
defaultPrefs.edit().putString(NAME, "Hello world!");
defaultPrefs.edit().commit();
```

To

```
defaultPrefs.edit().putString(NAME, "Hello world!").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
defaultPrefs.edit().putString(NAME, "Hello world!");
defaultPrefs.edit().commit();
```

to this:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = defaultPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(NAME, "Hello world!");
    editor.commit();
```

and it should work

Comment: @the_prole are you sure that this answer does not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This always seemed to work for me
Context context = YourFragmentName.this;
String NAME = "";

SharedPreferences share = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
share.getString(NAME, NAME);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = share.edit();
editor.putString(NAME, "myPref");
editor.apply();

//then get your string
String commitedString =  share.getString(NAME, "");
```